# Android - Custom Widget doesnt update

Tags: android, widget

I'm trying to make a widget to my app, but it doesnt update.
I just need to change the textview text and open an activity when a press a button, but none of them works...

the code:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.newswidget);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvNews, "prueba1");
    views.setString(R.id.tvNews, "setText", "prueba3");

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DoctorChatAndroid.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ibNext, pendingIntent);

    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(i, views);
    }
}
```

the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_ff"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibLast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_rew"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ibNext"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNews"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/nwNoNewAnswer"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ibLast"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the other xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="294dp"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="3000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/newswidget">
</appwidget-provider>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo in the last line:

```
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(i, views);
```

should be

```
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], views);
```

Or, better yet, do a for each loop

```
for (int i : appWidgetIds)
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(i, views);
```