# Updating Android Widget with user input

Tags: java, android

I am currently trying to implement a configuration activity which allows for manipulating the widget.

I have looked at the [official document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html), as well as many other blogs,

but do not understand how to change the content of the widget through the configuration activity.

I want to set the String `targetName` to a `TextView` in `R.layout.widget_layout`.

It says I need to update the widget through the configuration activity,
but what happens to the `onUpdate` code in **WidgetProvider.java** if I update it in the configuration activity? This is the part that is confusing me the most.

Here is part of my code:

**Configure.java extending ActionBarActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_configure);
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);

    context = this;

    final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        appWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }

    final AppWidgetManager widgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.batteryText);
    final int targetId;

    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    loadListView(); // not present here
    registerForContextMenu(listView);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            targetName = serverArrayList.get(position).getName();

            widgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

            Intent resultValue = new Intent();
            resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

**WidgetProvider.java extending AppWidgetProvider**

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a bit more research,
I found this question.
Despite the title being a bit misleading,
I think I've solved it, so I'll be closing this question.

[Android - Custom Widget doesnt update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808157/android-custom-widget-doesnt-update?rq=1)